# Smooth Streaming to android

Tags: video-streaming, smoothing, smooth-streaming-player, smooth-streaming

I have set up smooth streaming from IIS7  and it is working fine on Silverlight and iPhone.

Is it possible to use the following live URL stream to be streamed to Android devices ?

URL  -   httpL//webURL/stream.isml/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8

Comment: Hi did you manage to work it out ? Exoplayer? Doesnt seem to work with mediaplayer even with .ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl) format..;(

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is... some Android devices are able to play HLS video. On your case, you converted your Smooth Streaming video to HLS. Android version 2.3-4.0 can play HLS via Flash... the modern versions like 4.x can play it using the video API via "MediaPlayer" component.